# Download executable script from GitHub preserving +x permissions

Tags: permissions, git, wget, curl, github

I want to make a GitHub repository of all relevant scripts I posted here as answers.

But to keep it ultimately simple for the users, I would like to give them a single command to download the script file from my repository directly, without having to install `git` first to `git clone` the entire repository.

I know I can use `wget` to download a single file, but when I use the "Raw" link of a file (e.g. https://github.com/AskUbuntu-Answers/dupe-check/raw/master/dupe-check), the file will get default `umask` permissions and therefore has no execution bit set. But I don't want that the user still has to run `chmod +x`.

The script files are committed pushed to the repository with correct execution bits, they are also preserved when I use `git clone` to get the entire repository.

**What is the simplest way to retrieve (and sometimes automatically execute) a single file from GitHub preserving its executing permission without having to install `git` and cloning the entire repository?**

Comment: Automatically setting the executable permission without making the user somehow run `chmod` / change their umask I'd say would be impossible. GitHub AFAIK doesn't support anything other than HTTPS, so I'd say using a protocol which allows to keep permissions would be impossible either. Executing the file automatically on the other hand would be easy, something like `wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AskUbuntu-Answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check | env python3`.

Comment: @kos Ewww. Something like `python3 <(wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AskUbuntu-Answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check)` would be better, if only to prevent any accidental use of stdin from chewing up the script.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use gists instead of a git repository. Repository by nature is supposed to be a collection of files. Gists on the other hand are single files. Something like this

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SergKolo/d77dd46e9d936b5871e1829a2afd79c3/raw/726f39be5e0a939e06ed89239d2c350451b81316/get_unity_viewports.sh \
&& chmod +x ./get_unity_viewports.sh
```

But if you insist on using a repository , instead of 1 command , combine 2 into 1. Rememeber that we can specify interpreter for the code.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/au-answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check  > dupe-check && python3 dupe-check
```

And that's how it runs

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/au-answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check\                                          
>   > dupe-check && python3 dupe-check
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7580  100  7580    0     0   6484      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  6489
Checked 1 files in total, 0 of them are duplicates by content.
```

Same with `wget`

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/au-answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check && python3 dupe-check                     
--2016-04-24 21:17:35--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/au-answers/dupe-check/master/dupe-check
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 23.235.44.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|23.235.44.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7580 (7.4K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘dupe-check.1’

100%[==================================================================================>] 7,580       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2016-04-24 21:17:36 (470 MB/s) - ‘dupe-check.1’ saved [7580/7580]

Checked 2 files in total, 2 of them are duplicates by content.
Here's a list of all duplicate files:

'dupe-check' (./dupe-check)
'dupe-check.1' (./dupe-check.1)
```

**Variation on the theme**

Get the URL of raw file by right clicking  on the  `raw` button in github

```
wget https://github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/raw/master/dupe-check
```

Comment: O.o why would you use `curl` at all then? `wget`'s default behaviour is to save to a file (and usually it gets the filenames right). Also: `wget` default, `curl` not default.

Comment: Almost the same thing

Answer (score 2):

## Get the tarballs!

Even though Github doesn't expose this in the site (apparently [they did ages ago](https://github.com/blog/12-tarball-downloads)), they provide `tar.gz` files of the repositories.

```
wget -qO - https://github.com/<user>/repo>/archive/master.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 <repo>-master/<filename>
```

`<user>`, `<repo>`, `<filename>` are what you'd expect them to be. `--strip-components` is use to prevent `tar` from creating a directory named after the repo.

Therefore:

```
$ wget -O - https://github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/archive/master.tar.gz | tar zx --strip-components=1 dupe-check-master/dupe-check
--2016-04-25 08:28:50--  https://github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/archive/master.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.128
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.128|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://codeload.github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/tar.gz/master [following]
--2016-04-25 08:28:51--  https://codeload.github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/tar.gz/master
Resolving codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)... 192.30.252.160
Connecting to codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)|192.30.252.160|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2470 (2.4K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                                           100%[========================================================================================================================================>]   2.41K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2016-04-25 08:28:52 (21.5 MB/s) - written to stdout [2470/2470]

$ ll dupe-check 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 muru muru 7.5K Mar  5 21:46 dupe-check
```

I'm not convinced this is a particularly friendly way. An additional `chmod +x` is IMO infinitely preferable.

### Failed attempts

#### Get the zips!

You can process substitution on zsh to extract the zips linked on the Github repo page. Github, thankfully, adds extra metadata to zips so that permissions are preserved. `unzip` on Ubuntu is able to use that to restore permissions. So:

```
unzip -j =(wget -O - https://github.com/au-answers/dupe-check/archive/master.zip) dupe-check-master/dupe-check
```

Unfortunately, `=()` is a zsh thing. It creates a proper file instead of a FIFO. Bash doesn't have an equivalent. `<()` is always FIFO.

#### Git single files

You can get [a single file from repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1125476/2072269) using `git`. However, [Github doesn't support this](https://twitter.com/GitHubHelp/status/322818593748303873).